# Symfony2 - Displaying uploaded image in Twig from a Data Fixture or blog text

Tags: image, symfony, twig

How do I display an image in Twig loaded from a Doctrine Fixture that I've uploaded to the web/images folder? It displays when calling it from the acutal Twig but not from fixtures or entering the line when creating the blog text.

I have tried this line which doesn't load when in a fixture file (or inside the blog body when creating the blog entry) BUT when I use this line inside of the actual Twig file it does the image correctly?

```
<img src="{{ asset(['images/', blog.image]|join) }}" />
```

Using this to display the blogs in twig:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    <p>{{ blog.blog|truncate(2000) }}</p>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397894/symfony2-path-to-image-in-twig-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to use Twig's template_to_string function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing a quote mark in example 2

try
changing:

`<img class="alignleft" src="{{ asset('images/5375a30370200.jpeg) }}" alt="" width="290" height="275" />`

to:
`<img class="alignleft" src="{{ asset('/images/5375a30370200.jpeg') }}" alt="" width="290" height="275" />`

Or set a new variable

`{% set src = 'images/' ~ blog.image %}
<img class="alignleft" src="{{ asset( src ) }}" alt="" width="290" height="275" />`

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to add more information before the site went down. See updated question.

Comment: Tried both your solutions, they still do not load from a data fixture file or when creating the blog text manually and adding the code in.