# Display blob image in symfony 2

Tags: image, symfony, twig, assetic

I need to display images stored in my database, from users in my symfony 2 application. 
I've searched and I found examples such as:

[Php Display Image Blob from Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)

The line:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

It didn't worked for me.
How to return an image file and display it in user's profile or a gallery page?

Answer (score 2):

I created this action that searches the blob data in my table: **Empleado**.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/employee/photo/{id}", name="zk_time_employee_photo", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
     */
    public function photoAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $workerId = $request->get('id');
        if (empty($workerId))
           //throw exception

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('ZkTimeBundle:Empleado');

        $photo = $repository->findPhoto($workerId);
        if (empty($photo))
            //throw exception

        $response = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($photo) {
            echo stream_get_contents($photo);
        });

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        return $response;
    }
```

This part is essential (works for both formats, no matters the original format stored):

```
 $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/png');<br>
 OR
 $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');<br>
```

In order to display it I chose:

```
<img src="{{ asset(path('zk_time_employee_photo', {'id': employee.Id})) }}"/>
```

The base is the same for multiple images (**carousel**) or a **gallery**.
I hope this helps, because the web has empty results about it or not focused in Symfony2. Mainly, pure PHP.

### This guys were very helpful:

[Answer #1: symfony2-how-to-display-download-a-blob-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206963/symfony2-how-to-display-download-a-blob-field) 
[Answer #2: symfony2-path-to-image-in-twig-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397894/symfony2-path-to-image-in-twig-template)