# How can i display a picture in my file twig type BLOB Symphony2?

Tags: symfony, web, twig

[Entity file[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n8LL.png)

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOQnw.png)

thx for your help

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022909/display-blob-image-in-symfony-2 there are also 2 other questions refered in answer, check them also.

Answer (score 0):

In **`Controller`**

```
$images = array();
$em = $this->getDoctrine->getManager();
$probleme = $em->getRepository('PiCrowdRiseWebBundle:Probleme')->findAll();
foreach ($probleme as $key => $entity) {
    $images[$key] = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($entity->getFoto()));
}

// ...

return $this->render('PiCrowdRiseWebBundle:Probleme:problemList.html.twig', array(
    'problemes' => $probleme,
    'images' => $images,
));
```

**View:**

```
{% for key, entity in problemes %}
   {# ... #}
   <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ images[key] }}" />
   {# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning embedding images inside the html is a rather bad idea - rendering performance decreases and page load increases. I think it would be better if the image is served as a `<img src="link-to-controller"/>` where the `controller` actually streams the content. This way the page will actually render and the client will be waiting only for the image(s) to load.

Comment: that doesn't work maybe this line is not correct    <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ images[key] }}" />